# Why can't I access the sub-properties of a JSON object fetched from my API in express

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, react-hooks, mern

I'm trying to bring an object called *products* through React Hooks to my frontend using Axios, from a simple API that I have created with express, and apparently everything works fine as long as I do not try to access properties that are inside an object in the main object, because that is when I try this which React throws me the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

ProductScreen
src/screens/ProductScreen.js:40

  37 |     text={`${product.numReviews} reviews`}
  38 |   />
  39 | </ListGroup.Item>
> 40 | <ListGroup.Item>Precio: ${product.type[0].price}</ListGroup.Item>
     | ^  41 | <ListGroup.Item>
  42 |   Descripción: <br /> {product.description}
  43 | </ListGroup.Item>

View compiled

▶ 16 stack frames were collapsed.
```

If I don't access **product.type [0] .price**, which is an object within the main object, everything is rendered correctly.

The following is the code of the component in React that is giving me problems:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Row, Col, Image, ListGroup, Card, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Rating from '../components/Rating';
import axios from 'axios';

const ProductScreen = ({ match }) => {
  const [product, setProduct] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProduct = async () => {
      const product = await axios.get(`/api/products/${match.params.id}`);

      setProduct(product.data);
    };

    fetchProduct();
  }, [match]);

  return (
    <>
      <Link className='btn btn-dark my-3' to='/'>
        Volver
      </Link>
      <Row>
        <Col md={6}>
          <Image src={product.image} alt={product.name} fluid />
        </Col>
        <Col md={3}>
          <ListGroup varian='flush'>
            <ListGroup.Item>
              <h3>{product.name}</h3>
            </ListGroup.Item>
            <ListGroup.Item>
              <Rating
                value={product.rating}
                text={`${product.numReviews} reviews`}
              />
            </ListGroup.Item>
            <ListGroup.Item>Precio: ${product.type[0].price}</ListGroup.Item>
            <ListGroup.Item>
              Descripción: <br /> {product.description}
            </ListGroup.Item>
          </ListGroup>
        </Col>
        <Col>
          <Card>
            <ListGroup variant='flush'>
              <ListGroup.Item>
                <Row>
                  <Col>Precio:</Col>
                  <Col>
                    <strong>$</strong>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </ListGroup.Item>
              <ListGroup.Item>
                <Row>
                  <Col>Status:</Col>
                  <Col></Col>
                </Row>
              </ListGroup.Item>
              <ListGroup.Item>
                <Button className='btn-block' type='button'>
                  Agregar al carrito
                </Button>
              </ListGroup.Item>
            </ListGroup>
          </Card>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </>
  );
};

export default ProductScreen;
```

Where it can be seen that I am using React Hooks to bring the information from the backend, specifically the following lines of code are those that perform this task:

```js
  const [product, setProduct] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProduct = async () => {
      const product = await axios.get(`/api/products/${match.params.id}`);

      setProduct(product.data);
    };

    fetchProduct();
  }, [match]);
```

Saving the JSON object in the *product* variable

---

I think a key point in the problem is the fact that if I go to Network in the browser developer tools, the Header of the fetch object gives me:

```
 - Content-Type: text/html; charset = UTF-8 
 - Status Code: 200 
 - Response:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta name="description" content="El sabor del norte a tu casa" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/logo192.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css"
      integrity="sha512-+4zCK9k+qNFUR5X+cKL9EIR+ZOhtIloNl9GIKS57V1MyNsYpYcUrUeQc9vNfzsWfV28IaLL3i96P9sdNyeRssA=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <title>Bienvenido a Grill Shop</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  <script src="/static/js/bundle.js"></script><script src="/static/js/0.chunk.js"></script><script src="/static/js/main.chunk.js"></script><script src="/main.c767f2926d55ce283409.hot-update.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Where we can clearly see that it is not bringing me any JSON object, which explains why it throws the undefined error when I try to access the properties of the object

I have checked my server file and the response from the backend to the get request made in the frontend and precisely the response is a JSON object
This is why I don't understand why when trying to bring this object to the frontend the response from the server is an HTML / Text object

The following is the code of my API - server in express:

```js
const express = require('express');
const products = require('./data/products');

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('API is running...');
});

app.get('/api/products', (req, res) => {
  res.json(products);
});

app.get('/api/products/:id', (req, res) => {
  const product = products.find((p) => p._id === req.params.id);
  res.json(product);
});

app.listen(5000, console.log('Server running on port 5000'));
```

The following image shows the response I get from the backend:

[image]

As you can see, my API is running on port 5000, while my frontend on port 3000. In my frontend configuration file I added a proxy that points to port 5000 to be able to access the backend service

I thank you in advance, because I have spent several days trying to solve the problem but I have not found the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use an empty object as default value (`useState({})`). When the component mounts it will send out your network request, however it takes some time for the response to come through. During this time the default argument `{}` is used as `product`. For this reason `product.type` and all other properties you access will return `undefined`.

When using React you must explicitly tell what to render at all times, even if this means nothing should render.

An easy solution would be to use a default value of `null`, and only render something when `product` is truthy.

```
const [product, setProduct] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
  const fetchProduct = async () => {
    const product = await axios.get(`/api/products/${match.params.id}`);
    setProduct(product.data);
  };

  fetchProduct();
}, [match]);

// render nothing during the time product is loading
if (!product) return null;

return <>render product</>;
```

Alternatively you could also choose to render something to indicate that `product` is loading.

```
// assuming you use null as default
if (product) {
  // product is loaded
  return <>render product</>;
} else {
  // product is loading
  return <>loading...</>;
}
```

Comment: The error that is displayed in the browser when rendering the component has been fixed, but still cannot access the child properties of the JSON object and is fetching the html/text content type instead of JSON on the get request. Any idea why this keeps happening? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JJS_Vegu Have you already checked what the response is by placing a `console.log(product.data)` after fetching it using axios?

Comment: Now it's seems to work! for some reason I didn't see that was working before. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are not telling the frontend to use port 5000 when querying the backend.

This line:

```
const product = await axios.get(`/api/products/${match.params.id}`)
```

Will perform a request to the same host it is coming from (localhost:3000) so the whole url will be:

`http://localhost:3000/api/products/${match.params.id}`

Just set the proper host and you will be fine:

```
const product = await axios.get(BASE_URL + `/api/products/${match.params.id}`)
```

where `BASE_URL` should be a global constant you can change accordingly to where you deploy your backend and, when developing on your localmachine, should be `http://localhost:5000`

Comment: Doesn't seem to solve anything, instead, does not bring me any data with this. That's why I'm using the proxy to port 5000, i think so.